# I'm having a problem with setting my custom login page on Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I definitely set my SecurityConfiguration class correctly(at least from my knowledge) but if I direct to localhost:8001 on my browser, the default Spring login page seems to keep showing up.

my login.html is under resources/templates/user/login

And in my SecurityConfiguration, I set the loginPage() method to exactly "/user/login"

I set the Authentication manager and UserDetails etc login logic but there may be little errors to where the authentication process isn't working (I can't test it because I can't even get through the default login page)
but I'm sure that wont be of any disruption for my custom login page not being set.

I even set to disable Spring default on my Application class' main method.

I'll provide as much of my codes.

[[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3O2P.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5b3y.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91dAd.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elY4C.png)

Comment: posting code as images is against the stack overflow rules, please update your question with well formatted code. Its very rude to not read the rules before posting https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors voted to close

Answer (score -1):

Spring Security provides inbuilt functionality so can directly access login page by sharing api in formLogin method. As per new updates it uses lambda expression. Please check this github example.
I have attached link. Please verify : https://github.com/mMosiur/bookystore/blob/main/src/main/java/edu/umcs/bookystore/configurations/SecurityConfiguration.java
Try this below code :
`.formLogin((login) -> login //.loginPage("/user/login") //.failureUrl("/user/login?error") .loginPage( "/login" ).permitAll() .failureUrl( "/failed" ) .defaultSuccessUrl("/verifyLogin"))`

It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hey! thank you for your response! It took a hot minute for me to figure this out and I just started commenting out everything in my SecurityConfiguration class and it was the WebSecurity ignore code I had written out! 

@Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer configure() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**", "/images/**", "/js/**", "/lib/**"); 

I didn't provide this code in the post because I didn't think it would be the problem and I still don't know why.... Although thank you for your response and if you have any advice on this, would love to hear back!